# Operator has unexpected output behavior when using Info Panel feedback

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I am observing a behavior of the `bpy.types.Operator` which I really don't understand and I cannot find any documentation regarding this problem.

When executing a script like:

```
import bpy
class TEST_OT_logger(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.logger"
    bl_label = 'test'
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, 'Printing report to Info window.')
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
bpy.utils.register_class( TEST_OT_logger )
```

I expect a message in the info panel.
But dependent how I call the operator I get different results.

When using f3  -> test, I get the expected result of a info-panel message.

When calling the operator in the script like  `bpy.ops.test.logger("INVOKE_DEFAULT")`, I get only a console feedback.

When called in the python console I get the following feedback only in the python console.

```
>>> bpy.ops.test.logger("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
Info: Printing report to Info window.
{'FINISHED'}
```

Why does it behave like this and is there a possibility to get a info-panel feedback when called in a script?

Comment: Will speculate on _"why?"_ -> provides feedback in UI when invoked from UI.  Re python console it redirects `stdout` to itself. _eg_ `print("foo")` prints to blender python console, not system console. Possibly a design choice, do we necessarily  want feedback from all operators called in a script?

Comment: I see. I wish I could find a better documentation to these things, but it kinda makes sense, specially the python console feedback.
I still have a bit of a problem with this though.. As far as I figured out the operators are mainly displayable as buttons. But how can I properly trigger an operator as if its an UI input after I enter a string? StringProperty won't work with the logic from above, and I could not find any help on how to display an operator as a String Input field..